# Error on Simulating 8-input NOR gate with Proteus 8

Tags: logic-gates, proteus

I`m new to Proteus.

I want to simulate a logic circuit with Proteus 8, I want to use an 8-Input NOR Gate (4078) and some 4-Input AND Gates (4082), but when I want to simulate, there is some Errors :

```
No model specified for U12. [U12]
No model specified for U15:A. [U15:A]
No model specified for U15:B. [U15:B]
No model specified for U16:A. [U16:A]
No model specified for U17:A. [U17:A]
No model specified for U17:B. [U17:B]
No model specified for U18:A. [U18:A]
No model specified for U18:B. [U18:B]
No model specified for U19:A. [U19:A]
Simulation FAILED due to partition analysis error(s).
```

I know the errors means there is no simulation model for this devices

I want to know what device I should use as an 8-Input OR (or NOR) and 4-Input AND gates ?

Is it possible to change the device model ? or I should redesign my circuit with new devices ?

Answer (score 2):

First, click on the option "show only parts with models" in the device selector. Then build your logic functions out of gates that *do* have models.

An 8 input NOR gate can be made from two 4 input OR gates going to a 2 input NOR gate. For a 4 input AND gate you just need a 4 input NAND gate followed by an inverter.

However I suspect there might be a problem with your installation, because in mine (V8.3 SP2) the 4078 and 4082 both have models.